# htaccess URL Rewrite Not working with first rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules setup for my blog and they seem to work just fine.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|(modules|css|files|fonts|ico|img|js)/)

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)$ /framework/?p=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/search/([^/]*)$ /framework/?p=$1&search=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/search/([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)$ /framework/?p=$1&search=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

So I was feeling confident and wanted to add one more rule for the just the basic page.

so I added this rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /framework/?p=$1 [L]
```

so that my htaccess file now looks like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|(modules|css|files|fonts|ico|img|js)/)

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /framework/?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)$ /framework/?p=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/search/([^/]*)$ /framework/?p=$1&search=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/search/([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)$ /framework/?p=$1&search=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

but for if I go to `http://www.example.com/framework/blog` I get a `500 Internal Server Error` if I take out the line and go to `http://www.example.com/framework/blog/page/2` it loads my second page without any issues.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: may be $1 position not found try with RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /framework/ [L]

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your line of thought. if it the rule does not have `?p=$1` how will it now that `p=blog` | Added the line you suggested, still got the `500` error though.

Comment: needed to add these two lines `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Is this .htaccess placed in `/framework/` directory OR in root?

Comment: it is in the `/framework/` directory

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /framework/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/([^/]*)$ ?p=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/search/([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)$ ?p=$1&search=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/search/([^/]*)$ ?p=$1&search=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```